# Robocode Responsive Turning

Tags: java, math, equation, degrees, robocode

I'm trying to make a robot for robocode that always turns perpendicular when it sees a robot.

If you don't know what robocode is just imagine a top down game where direction is recorded in degrees

I've already made an equation that does what I want but it is very inefficient

(e.getHeading is the direction the target is facing,
 getHeading is the direction I'm facing
 note that also there is a method getBearing that shows angle relative to the enemy)

```
turnRight( (e.getHeading() + 90) - getHeading());
```

The problem though is that it will sometimes go the long way around rather than the shortest route. What better equation could I use to always turn the right way?

Answer (score 0):

You would have to normalize the result of

```
degdiff = (e.getHeading() + 90) - getHeading()
```

so that it is in the range -180..180. This is either

```
if(degdiff >  180) degdiff -=360;
if(degdiff < -180) degdiff +=360;
```

or

```
degdiff = (degdiff%360 + 540)%360 -180
```

and then

```
turnRight(degdiff)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
setTurnRightRadians(normalRelativeAngle(e.getBearingRadians() + Math.PI / 2))
```

`e.getHeading()` is enemy's heading.